# message box to show in right column

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to design the responsive contact form where the layout is name, email, subject fields be in one column and message field be in the another column. I could not make that message field appear in another column though I have used the `width as 50%`. Here is the demo

http://jsbin.com/vuxojuqeve/edit?html,css,output

The code

```css
#responsive-form {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-row {
  width: 100%;
}

.form-row input {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.button {
  float: left;
  background: #CA0002;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: none;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="text"],
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.half-size {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="responsive-form" class="clearfix">
  <div class="half-size">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="column">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="column">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="column">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="column">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="half-size">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="column">
        <textarea class="form-control" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="column">
      <input type="submit" name="name" class="button">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is what I wanted with submit button on the left column

[image]

Comment: Dont use floats, use flexbox or css grid there are heaps of great courses on flexbox and a really great course on css grid just came out https://cssgrid.io/  this will allow you to make layouts like this super easy in the future

Comment: markup structure change allow here or you want the expected layout with current markup structure?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your containers to display:inline-block, as they are block level elements by default and won't allow others to be positioned beside them.

I'm using 45% because 50% + 50% is not usually 100% when using inline-blocks because of an issue with whitespace, there are [some ways around it](https://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block), I'll let you decide for yourself which hack to use...

```css
#responsive-form {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-row {
  width: 100%;
}

.form-row input {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.button {
  float: left;
  background: #CA0002;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: none;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="text"],
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.half-size {
  width: 45%;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="responsive-form" class="clearfix">
  <div class="half-size">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="column">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="column">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="column">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="column">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="half-size">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="column">
        <textarea class="form-control" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="column">
      <input type="submit" name="name" class="button">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are columns, use **flexbox**.

Inputs and textarea width unit is `vw` and e.g. `min-width: 180px`.

#### Example

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

::placeholder,
input[type="submit"] {
  color: #BACEE7;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 15px;
}

.form input,
.form textarea {
  min-width: 180px;
  background: #F2F2F2;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form>.inputs {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.form>.inputs>input {
  width: 30vw;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 1.5vw;
}

.form>.inputs>input:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.form textarea {
  width: 35vw;
  padding-top: 80px;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}

.form input[type="submit"] {
  background: #CA0002;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <div class="inputs">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="first name">
    <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="last name">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email">
    <input type="text" name="organization" placeholder="organization">
    <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="phone">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </div>
  <div class="textarea">
    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" placeholder="message"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```